# Laravel Request Class Reflection Exception Does Not Exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting an error using a request class called RolesRequest in my store function in my controller, I have my controller in an Admin folder under controllers. When I change the name just to RoleRequest I still get the same error and I don't know why, I have tried to do a composer dump-autoload but that doesn't help I still get the same error. I'm using laravel 5.5.4 I think

Error Message:

```
Class App\Http\Requests\RolesRequest does not exist", exception: "ReflectionException"
```

// Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Role;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\RolesRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RolesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.roles');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(RolesRequest $request)
    {
        dd('hit');
    }
}
```

// RolesRequest Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RolesRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin');
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        switch($this->method())
        {
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE':
            {
                return [];
            }
            case 'POST':
            {
                $unique = [
                    'name'      => 'required|min:3|max:30|unique:roles,name',
                ];
                break;
            }
            case 'PUT':
            case 'PATCH':
            {
                $unique = [
                    'name'     => 'required|min:3|max:30|unique:roles,name,'. $this->id
                ];
                break;            
            }
            default:break;
        }      

        $rules = [
            'display_name' => 'required|min:4|max:50',
            'description'  => 'required|min:10|max:100'
        ]  

        return $unique + $rules;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check if there is more than 1 error happening? its possible the parser could error out on the file when trying to initially parse it which would cause it to not be able to be loaded hence not found ...  since you have a syntax error in the paste

Comment: Whats the syntax error in the paste

Comment: missing a semi-colon before the `return` in the file you are trying to load, `RolesRequest`

Comment: Thank you for that, that was what was making the error

Comment: np ... i might be able to come up with a lil explanation to make an answer

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those fun times when there is more than 1 error happening. You are seeing the second error.
The first error is the parser failing on a syntax error in the class you are trying to use. It is trying to load that file and fails so the file is never loaded, hence the class can not be found (the second error).

Its possible the error shown here is (2/2) in the error page. Check your error log to see if it is showing an error before your "class does not exist" error that you are seeing.

The `RolesRequest` file has a syntax error before the `return`. The array definition statement doesn't have a semicolon at the end.